# Django состояние кнопки

Tags: python, django

Как получить состояние кнопки (true or false)?

В таком случае ошибка идет:

```
t = request.POST['USD']
```

Comment: <button class = "btn btn-primary btn-sm " type="button" name = "USD">USD</button>

Comment: Что значит "состояние кнопки"? Что в ней `true`, а что `false`? Может, вы имели в виду, правильно ли заполнена форма?

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй так:

```
if request.POST.get('USD',False):
    toDo
else:
    toDo
```

Должно работать